# Como pegar uma palavra dentro de uma string (frase) em Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho uma duvida,

tenho uma string:

```
var frase = "Ola, bruno";
```

Preciso pegar o que esta escrito até a virgula e depois pegar o que esta escrito depois da virgula, por exemplo:

```
var ABC = "Ola";
var EFG = "Bruno";
```

Como proceder?

Comment: E no caso se eu tiver uma frase: "Oi Joao". Como faco pra pegar o Oi e o Joao separadamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outra forma é utilizando o método  `split()`, que divide uma string longa em partes delimitadas por um caractere específico e depois cria um array com essas partes.

```js
var frase = 'Ola, Bruno, Fullstack, developer';  
var retorno = frase.split(",");
console.log( retorno[0] );
console.log( retorno[1] );
console.log( retorno[2] );
console.log( retorno[3] );
```

A facilidade de se trabalhar com esse método é muito grande.

Exemplo em um loop:

```js
var frase = 'Ola, Bruno, Fullstack, developer';

var frase_array = frase.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < frase_array.length; i++) {
   console.log(frase_array[i]);
}
```

Caso deseje retirar os espaços

Use:  `frase_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");`

```js
var frase = 'Ola, Bruno, Fullstack, developer';

var frase_array = frase.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < frase_array.length; i++) {
   frase_array[i] = frase_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   console.log(frase_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando o método [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

O método retorna o index de determinado carácter em uma `string`. A partir daí é só trabalhar com esta informação.

Exemplo com o código da pergunta.

```js
var frase = 'Ola, bruno';

var index = frase.indexOf(',');

var a = frase.substring(0, index);
var b = frase.substring(index + 2);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

[Ou veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/HvoF/0)

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do @Leo Caracciolo, tanto o replace quanto o split são métodos do objeto String, assim, eles permitem que você faça encadeamento de métodos, por exemplo:

```js
const meuTexto = "Raul, Felipe, de, Melo";
const regexWhiteSpace = /\s/g;

console.log(meuTexto.replace(regexWhiteSpace, '').split(','))
```

E caso você saiba exatamente quais as informações que você está esperando receber e deseja criar variáveis com cada elemento no array, você pode usar o Destructuring do ES6, segue um exemplo:

```js
const nomeCompleto = "Raul, Melo";
const regexWhiteSpace = /\s/g;
const [nome, sobrenome] = nomeCompleto.replace(regexWhiteSpace,'').split(',')

console.log('nome:',nome)
console.log('sobrenome:',sobrenome)
```